# Lighting doesn't make objects cast shadows

Tags: lighting, shadows

I wanted to make a Solar system in Blender. Everything on the scene is made pitch black (including World), except planets and Sun. I want that planets cast shadows so I added an Emission node to the Sun, but planets are still fully visible. [image] All planets just have Image Texture nodes like this. [image]And this is Node Tree of the Sun. [image]My render engine is Cycles.

Comment: Could you add a picture of the node network of one of your planets ?

Comment: @Gorgious I've done it!

Comment: Do you have some ambient occlusion ? It is in the world properties. Without any lights the planets should'nt be visible in rendered view

Comment: @Gorgious But when I turn it off, Sun's texture disappears and planets are almost invisible, they are just slightly orange on the side that's facing the Sun

Comment: @Gorgious is right. You need to turn up the Emission and disable the AO.

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ But still Sun doesn't have its texture

Comment: Well, of course. That's the (physically) correct result. If you want to get nice shadows AND the sun texture visible, you have to cheat a bit. You can [ask a new question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), about how to make such solar system.

Comment: @Gorgious Thx! But Sun is black beacause that light doesn't shine on it. Should I add another light specifically for the Sun

Comment: Oh, right, what you can do is make it transmissive in your principled shader. Although this will up the render time and can cause fireflies I believe

Comment: @Gorgious I solved the problem by placing Spot light above and under the Sun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable Ambient Occlusion in the world properties.

If you use the shader of the sun itself to light the scene, your texture will be overwhelmed by the emission part and any detail will be lost.

You can emulate the light from the sun by using a point light centered on the sun itself. Remember to set its size to a high enough number so that it is bigger than the sun object or else light won't get through to your planets.
You can then set the emission strength of the sun to a low enough value that it still appears to be glowing but you still see all the details of your texture.
[image]

Details on the point light (Adjust these settings depending on your scene) :

[image]